# SceneKit in Xcode

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit, collada

I have a Collada `.dae` file that has animations. These animations are using Geometry Morphers and play just fine in the app. However, Xcode doesn't play them at all when I change the coefficients in the inspector panel, or when I click the preview eyeball. It just does nothing.

Clearly it seems like it's hooked up properly if it works in the app, any idea why Xcode preview isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Morph Targets need to have the identical number of vertices as well as the vertices for morphing need to have exactly the same arrangement in Xcode.

Here's an excerpt of `SCNMorpher` class from [developers' documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmorpher):

> A morpher and its target geometries may be loaded from a scene file or created programmatically. The base geometry and all target geometries must be topologically identical—that is, they must contain the same number and structural arrangement of vertices.

Hope this helps.